# Why am I not being able to see my combined profiles flair image yet?

Tags: support, network-profile, combined-flair

The individual profile flairs are now showing correct rep but even though I've profile having rep > 200 still it is showing

[image]

This profile [page](https://stackexchange.com/users/aa282e09-3d32-4f77-a1d6-51449ee8a367?tab=accounts) shows my rep for different SE sites.

Do I need to wait more or what?

Comment: PS: the image I've used in the question is linking to actual url of my networked profile image flair so it is showing current status at any time. Hope this image gets changed to something better looking soon :D

Comment: It's now showing all three where you have more than 200 rep - took less than Rebecca said. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flair is cached for up to 24 hours.  Please give it some time to update and then everything should be fine. (:

Comment: Ok! That's fine. Thanks! I thought there is some problem with linking of my accounts. :)